# Swift 5 Xcode 12 CoreBluetooth State always unknown

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, swift5, xcode12

We tried using the standard autogenerated code for running bluetooth in swift:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
            print("Unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("Resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("Not supported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("unAuthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("Bluetooth Off")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("Bluetooth On")
            
    }
```

The state is always unknown even though we ran it on an actual device

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show more code. Specifically, how are you creating and retaining your `CBCentralManager` instance? Do you get a Bluetooth permission prompt?